# See logs and queue depth of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

I am using Active MQ Artemis that is embedded within JBoss EAP 7.2.0 for messaging. When we send and receive a message to a queue that we have created, I was unable to find the log in server.log of jboss. Can you please guide me in which log I can find the log when I send/receive any message to/from queue and how to see the queue depth?

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate ActiveMQ Artemis audit logging:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.apache.activemq.audit.message:add(level=INFO, use-parent-handlers=true)
```

You have queue metrics that are exposed at the queue itself

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=DLQ:read-resource(include-runtime)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "consumer-count" => undefined,
        "dead-letter-address" => undefined,
        "delivering-count" => 0,
        "durable" => true,
        "entries" => ["java:/jms/queue/DLQ"],
        "expiry-address" => undefined,
        "legacy-entries" => undefined,
        "message-count" => 0,
        "messages-added" => 0,
        "paused" => undefined,
        "queue-address" => undefined,
        "scheduled-count" => 0,
        "selector" => undefined,
        "temporary" => undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to execute the command in JBoss CLI? Can you please give me the full command?

Comment: I had executed the below command in jboss cli:  /subsystem=logging/logger=org.apache.activemq.audit.message:add(level=DEBUG), but  when I sent a message in activemq, it is not getting logged in server.log

Comment: Did you change you file log level too ?